# Could not catch the click event for a class which is appended by js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I appended the checkbox input field from javascript. after that, I need to catch click event of that checkbox field. But I could not. I tried with these following instruction:
 - [An append in jquery code and click function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658579/an-append-in-jquery-code-and-click-function)
 - [jQuery 1.9 .live() is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354040/jquery-1-9-live-is-not-a-function).

This is my code

```
var htmlData='<input type="checkbox" name="is_pay[]" class="is_pay">';
$('.container').append(htmlData);

$('.is_pay').on('click', function(){
        alert('hi');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that item does not exist when the script is run, so listen for a click on `.container`:

```
var htmlData='<input type="checkbox" name="is_pay[]" class="is_pay">';
$('.container').append(htmlData);

$(".container").on("click", ".is_pay", function() {
    alert("hi");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Event handler will only run if element exist on the page therefore your script click handler is not worked as you are adding checkbox dynamically .

If any new element injected to page dynamically then use delegated event to attach event handler . Replace click handler with the following code

```
$("document").on("click", ".is_pay", function() {
    alert("hi");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply handle with [.click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

```js
var htmlData='<input type="checkbox" name="is_pay[]" class="is_pay">';
$('.container').append(htmlData);

$('.is_pay').click(function(event) {
   alert('hi');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'></div>
```